# Work flow about babel + browserify

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

All:

When I followed the tutorial of Facebook React, it only talked about how to transpile with Babel, but no content with browserify, I wonder if I use gulp, how to build the work flow with babel and browserify.

For example:

1. Transpile all *.js files in /js folder, and copy them to /build/js
2. When 1 is ready, broserify all /build/js/*.js into bundle.js and copy to /dist/js
3. Copy *.html to /dist/

That is it! Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to glob files, or is there an entry file you can point browserify to and let it pull in the rest of the files via the dependency graph?

Comment: unless you're really committed to using browserify, checkout http://jspm.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that, or compile and browserify in the same step with the babelify transform for browserify.

Here is a basic example of how to compile and bundle modules in one step using babelify, and assuming an entry file that has a dependency graph that includes all of the modules you want to bundle.

```js
browserify('./js/entry')
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./dist/bundle.js'));
```

Comment: Thanks, could u give me an exxample of that. I tried using Gulp to do this, but the current problem is the browserify part in the task flow can not find the file transpiled in the /build/js, I guess it is because transpiling(babel) is not finished by the time when browserify starts to work.

Comment: Currently all my js files are concatenated to a single file, then I just pipe that result with Babel. in what stage do I use browserify?

Comment: @kuan You never answered my question.